# 3D plot with different pic orientation

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to illustrate 3D system, with rays being reflected from one surface vertical to another that would also reflect it horizontally. I tried different styles to control the path and appearance of the rays, but I'm not getting clear image. For instance in the first the orientation of the horizontally reflecting surface is not oriented the right way. Hope the image can clear out what is my problem. Any helps appreciated.

Trial one

```
\documentclass[%
% border=1pt
  border={20pt 40pt 40pt 80pt} % left bottom right top
]{standalone}    
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}    
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing} %  
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Ground}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tikzset{
        pics/RIS/.style n args={3}{ % numRows, numCols, elementSize
            code={
            \def\numRows{5}
    \def\numCols{5}
    \def\elementSize{0.35}
    \def\gap{0.1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xStart}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yStart}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\zStart}{#3} % Adjust zStart for height
    
    \foreach \row in {1,...,\numRows}{
        \foreach \col in {1,...,\numCols}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xCoord}{\xStart+(\col-1)*(\elementSize+\gap)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yCoord}{\yStart+(\row-1)*(\elementSize+\gap)}
            % Adjust below for the 3D perspective and orientation
            \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[fill=blue!20!white!30,draw=black] (axis cs:\xCoord,\yCoord,\zStart) -- ++(axis direction cs:\elementSize,0,0) -- ++(axis direction cs:0,\elementSize,0) -- ++(axis direction cs:-\elementSize,0,0) -- cycle;}
            \temp
        }
    }
            }
        }
    };

\tikzset{block/.style={draw, rectangle,                 width=\textwidth, height=1.5*\textwidth,drop shadow}}
\begin{axis}[ clip = false,
                colormap={winter}{
                HTML={EAF2F8}
                HTML={EBF5FB} 
                },
                xtick=\empty,
                ytick=\empty,
                ztick=\empty,
                axis line style={draw=none},
                zmin=-10, zmax=70]
    \addplot3[surf,samples=25,x=-0.5:0.5, y=-0.5:0.5] { -0.01*x^2-0.01*y^2 };
    \node[name=GS1] at (axis cs:0,0,16){}
       ;
   
    \node[name=satone,rotate=-20] at (axis cs:17,17,50){};
    \node[name=sat,rotate=-30] at (axis cs:12,15,120){};

   

    \node[name=satthree,rotate=-30] at (axis cs:6,15,50){};   



     \path(GS1)--++(-120:10pt)--++(47:30pt)node[coordinate,name=A]{};
     
    \path(satthree.west)--++(80:55pt)--++(0:0pt)node[coordinate,name=B]{};
       \draw[-,dashed](A)--(B);
       
     \pic[rotate=-45] at (0,0,0) {RIS={-10}{14}{60}};
     \pic[rotate=-45] at (0,0,0) {RIS={-15}{12}{70}};
    \pic[rotate=90,name=RIS1] at (axis cs:12,22,-50) {RIS={0}{0}{0}};
\path(sat.center)--++(0:20pt)node[coordinate,name=A]{};
      \draw[-,thick](A)--++(-3,-10,-9)node[coordinate,name=D]{};

      \node[name=sattwo,rotate=50] at (axis cs:14,18,20){};
      \pic[rotate=45] at (0,0,0) {RIS={10}{-2}{-160}};

     \path(sattwo.center)--++(0:7pt)node[coordinate,name=A]{};
      \draw[-,thick](A)--++(-3,-10,-16)node[coordinate,name=C]{};
      
       \path(satthree.center)--++(0:20pt)node[coordinate,name=A]{};
       \draw[-,thick](A)--++(-1,-14,2)node[coordinate,name=E]{};
       \path(satthree.center)--++(11.5:20pt)node[coordinate,name=A]{};
       \draw[-,thick](A)--++(-19,15,-95)node[coordinate,name=B]{};


       %Rays 
        \path(GS1)--++(-120:10pt)--++(47:30pt)node[coordinate,name=A]{};
        \path[-](D)--++(-9,4.5,-80)node[coordinate,name=D]{};
        \path[-](satone)--++(8:-12pt)node[coordinate,name=satone]{};
       \draw[->,dashed,red](A)--(B)--(D)--(satone.center);



       
       
        \path[-](satone)--++(90:-5pt)node[coordinate,name=satone]{};
       \draw[->,dashed,red](A)--(E)--(C)--(satone.center);


       

    
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Trial two

```
\documentclass[%
    % border=1pt
      border={20pt 40pt 40pt 80pt} % left bottom right top
    ]{standalone}    
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}    
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing} %  
    \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{Ground}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
    \begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        pics/RIS/.style={ % No arguments needed
            code={
            % Fixed values for number of rows, columns, and element size
            \def\numRows{5}
            \def\numCols{5}
            \def\elementSize{0.5cm}
            \def\gap{0.1cm} % Space between squares
            \foreach \row in {1,...,\numRows}{
                \foreach \col in {1,...,\numCols}{
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xCoord}{(\col-1)*(\elementSize+\gap)}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yCoord}{(\row-1)*(\elementSize+\gap)}
                    % Draw squares
                    \draw[fill=blue!20] (\xCoord,\yCoord,0) rectangle ++(\elementSize,\elementSize,0);
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{block/.style={draw, rectangle,                 width=\textwidth, height=1.5*\textwidth,drop shadow}}
    \begin{axis}[ clip = false,
                    colormap={winter}{
                    HTML={EAF2F8}
                    HTML={EBF5FB} 
                    },
                    xtick=\empty,
                    view={60}{15},
                    ytick=\empty,
                    ztick=\empty,
                    axis line style={draw=none},
                    zmin=-10, zmax=70]
        \addplot3[surf,samples=25,x=-0.5:0.5, y=-0.5:0.5] { -0.01*x^2-0.01*y^2 };
        \node[name=Startingpoint] at (axis cs:0,0,16){Starting point}
           ;
          \addplot3[mesh, gray!50, domain=-30:30, samples=17, domain y=-30:30, samples y=17] {0}; 
          \addplot3 [patch, patch refines=4, patch type=rectangle, white, faceted color=red!50 ]  coordinates {(-30,0,8) (30,0,8) (30,0,-8) (-30,0,-8)};
         \pic[rotate=-190] at (axis cs:0,50,70) {RIS};
         \pic[rotate=-45] at (axis cs:0,0,0) {RIS};
         \pic[rotate=90,name=RIS1] at (axis cs:12,22,-50) {RIS};
         \pic[rotate=230,name=RIS3] at (axis cs:0,50,40) {RIS};
         \node[name=Endpoint,rotate=-20] at (axis cs:17,100,50){Endpoint};
         \path(Startingpoint)--++(-120:10pt)--++(47:30pt)node[name=A]{A};
        \draw[-,dashed](A)--(axis cs:0,50,70);
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]